# Unpinning accepted answers / Akzeptierte Antwort ist eine von vielen – hopp oder flopp?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, answers, accepted-answer

Auf SE.Meta wurde vor ein paar Tagen eine [neue Einstellung vorgestellt](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369568/466917): Ob die akzeptierte Antwort immer ganz oben angepinnt ist oder ob sie schlicht eine von vielen ist.  Die Einstellung gilt pro SE-Seite - ob deren Meta-Seite nochmal separat ist, weiß ich nicht. Liebe Mods, wie sieht es da aus?

Die Frage ist schlicht:

- Soll eine akzeptierte Antwort stets oben stehen?
- Oder soll sie sich allen Antworten unterordnen und lediglich bei "unentschieden" den höheren Anzeigeplatz einnehmen?

Als Beispiel habe ich diese [zufällig ausgewählte Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/31917/36160) gefunden:

- akzeptierte Antwort hat in Summe 11 Upvotes
- andere ältere Antwort hat in Summe 15 Upvotes.

---

A few days ago on SE.Meta a new [setting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369568/466917) got presented: unpin accepted answers from top of the answer queue - yeah or ney? This setting is per SE site.

The question for German.SE is as follows:

- Should the accepted answer be always on top regardless the sorting?
- Or should the accepted answer be just one of many and rank only higher in case of tie?

As example see this [random question](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/31917/36160):

- accepted answer has in sum 11 upvotes
- one older answer has in sum 15 upvotes

---

Die Antworten als Bild/ pictures for history purpose

- *accepted answer*
  [image: accepted answer]
- *(... with timestamp)*
- [image: and it's timestamp]
- *other answe*r
  [image: older answer with more upvotes]

Comment: Danke für den Hinweis! Die Rückmeldungen hier fallen typischerweise sehr spärlich aus, aber ich verfolge das weiter.

Comment: Da fast zwei Monate ohne nennenswertes Votum für *keep pin* ins Land gegangen sind, schließe ich, dass es den meisten gleichgültig ist.  Weil es nur Antworten für *unpin*  gibt,  und keine Abwertungen dazu, habe das hinterlegt.

Comment: A potentially relevant example here: https://german.stackexchange.com/q/2906/35111

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mein Eindruck ist, dass oft sehr schnell eine Antwort akzeptiert wird, wodurch diese Antwort ohnehin schon einen Vorteil hat. (Späteres Ändern der akzeptierten Antwort ist dagegen ziemlich selten.)

Ich fände es ungerechtfertigt, diesen Vorteil noch durch die automatisch bessere Platzierung zu verstärken, zumal die anderen positiven Bewertungen noch Aspekte einbeziehen können, die gar nicht im Fokus der ursprünglichen Frage standen. Anders formuliert: bei sprachlichen Fragen kann es mehrere relevante Aspekte geben, die nicht immer leicht zu priorisieren sind. Das wird durch den Wertungsprozess besser reflektiert als durch binäres *Akzeptieren*.

Comment: "dass oft sehr schnell eine Antwort akzeptiert wird". Ist das Unpinnen die beste Antwort? Wäre es nicht besser, zu erzwingen, dass eine Antwort, z.B. frühestens 48 Stunden nachdem sie gepostet wurde akzeptiert werden kann.

Comment: Das scheint ein anderer Vorschlag zu sein, der möglicherweise die unerwünschte Nebenwirkung hat, dass gar keine Antwort mehr akzeptiert wird. Zudem können wir uns nicht vor der  Entscheidung drücken, ob wir es beim Bevorzugen der akzeptierten Antwort belassen oder nicht.

Answer (score 10):

Ich bin dafür, dass die akzeptierte Antwort "eine von vielen" ist. Einerseits haben wir selten 10 Antworten auf eine Frage (=die akzeptierte verschwindet nie im Nirvana). Und andererseits erlebe ich es bei Duplikatsverweisen immer mal, dass die anno dunnemals akzeptierte Antwort "bisschen dünn" ist.

I'm pro setting "accepted answer is one of many".